# web service client side cache using tomcat server

Tags: java, web-services, caching

We are retrieving the data from web services using axis1.4 how can we implement the cache mechanism in java client code.

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an in-process cache like [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) or out of process cache like [memcached](http://memcached.org/).
If you choose to go with memcached, you can use [spymemcached](http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/) java client for memcached.